# Как получить значение ползунка Slider в JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, awt

Имеется слайдер:

```
Slider slider = new Slider();
slider.setMin(1);
slider.setMax(1000);
slider.setValue(500);
slider.setMajorTickUnit(499);
slider.setMinorTickCount(2);
slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
```

И есть слушатель события клавиши:

```
public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
if (ke.getCode().getName().equals("F12"))
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robot.delay(300);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robot.delay(300);
```

Как вот эту задержку (robot.delay) добавить в слайдер, что бы к примеру если бы я выбрал 25мс, то кликалось раз в 25мс(делаю автокликер)

Вот полный код:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;


public class Main extends Application {
    Stage window;
    Robot robot;
    Scene scene;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Автокликер");
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.getIcons().add(new Image("RoAwmnIqMH8.jpeg"));

        Slider slider = new Slider(0, 100, 50);
        slider.setMajorTickUnit(50);
        slider.setMinorTickCount(2);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider.setShowTickMarks(true);

        GridPane.setConstraints(slider, 0, 1);

        Label interva = new Label("Скорость клика");
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        GridPane.setConstraints(interva, 0, 0);
        grid.getChildren().addAll(interva, slider);

        scene = new Scene(grid, 200, 100);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler < KeyEvent > () {
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                if (ke.getCode().getName().equals("F12")) for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                    robot.delay(300);
                    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                    robot.delay(300);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы умеете значение слайдера в переменную записывать?

Comment: @LEQADA, Кажется, нет..

Comment: могу. вот: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f679974e9484ed4a137c

Comment: Хорошо, сделано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам всего лишь нужно написать `Listener` для `Slider`. Создайте глобальную `int` переменную `delayVal` и перезаписывайте из `newVal.intValue()`:

```
slider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> obsVal,
                        Number oldVal, Number newVal) {
        System.out.println(newVal.intValue());
        delayVal = newVal.intValue();
    }
});
```

А потом эту переменную используйте внутри слушателя кнопок, в качестве значения `delay`.

Comment: И да, у вас будет `NullPointerException` на этой строке `robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);`. А всё из-за того, что вы не создали объект `Robot`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Насчет исключения NullPointer я знаю, просто балуюсь, пробую разные фишки добавлять

Answer (score 1):

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;


public class Main extends Application {
    Stage window;
    Robot robot;
    Scene scene;
    private int current = 300; // 300 - default value

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.robot = new Robot();
        window = primaryStage; // лишнее присваение, если не используеться больше нигде window.
        window.setTitle("Автокликер");
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.getIcons().add(new Image("RoAwmnIqMH8.jpeg"));

        Slider slider = new Slider(0, 100, 50);
        slider.setMajorTickUnit(50);
        slider.setMinorTickCount(2);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider.setShowTickMarks(true);

        GridPane.setConstraints(slider, 0, 1);

        Label interva = new Label("Скорость клика"); // Тут скорее всего должно быть "Частота клика"
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        GridPane.setConstraints(interva, 0, 0);
        grid.getChildren().addAll(interva, slider);

        scene = new Scene(grid, 200, 100);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
        slider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue)
            {
                current = newValue.intValue();
            }
        });
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler < KeyEvent > () {
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.F12)) for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                    robot.delay(current);
                    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                    robot.delay(current);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение.